# JWPlayer Error Only within IOS build Using Ionic 4

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, jwplayer

I need to play JWplayer in my ios application. 
(no other player service)
The application is a hybrid application built for the ios platform using ionic 4 with angular.

JWPlayer work just fine within chrome 
but within ios build I get error num `101104` which is a Network error according to JWplayer [docs](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/errors-reference/)

I asked some friends and they told me it might be related to 
`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`in `info.plist` file.

So added this code to `config.xml`

```
<config-file parent="NSAppTransportSecurity" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
     <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true />
     </dict>
</config-file>
```

not to mention its not recommanded it did not help either.

In any case, this is my code:

-index.html

```
<!-- JwPlayer--> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/libraries/jwplayer-8.9.2/jwplayer.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="mykey"</script>
```

-player.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var jwplayer: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PlayerService {

  constructor() { }

  loadMedia(id,file_url) {
    jwplayer(id).setup({
      sources: [{
        label: "1080p",
        file: file_url,
        type: "mp4",
        }],
      width: "100%",
      height: "250",
      image: '',
      skin: { name: 'glow' },
      startparam: 'position',
      primary: "html5",
      hlshtml: true,
      enableFullscreen: 'true'
    });
    jwplayer();
  }
}
```

BTW android build does not show the above error also.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @VishwaDeepakSingh  not yet

Comment: @ZoharRevivo have you found a solution for your error? I got the Same. Under Android I found a Solution `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` but not yet for ios

Comment: The issue is that the jwplayer script attempts to load additional dependencies, and in an ionic ios application, ionic sets the protocol for those requests to ionic:// vs http or https. Reason surrounds the webview and how it functions. I am troubleshooting this issue as we speak. Were any of you able to resolve?